# What is differences between local Heroku and Heroku SaaS version?

Tags: heroku

I need information about differences between local Heroku, running on my computer by using `heroku local` command and Heroku in the cloud. I must compare these ways of deploying app on Heroku.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is only one way to deploy a heroku app, and that is to push it to the cloud (e.g. via `git push heroku master`).

The `heroku local` command simply allows you to run the code that constitutes your heroku app in your local git repo, on your local development machine/environment. This is to enable you to develop and test your code in your development environment, before you deploy to Heroku. So, `heroku local` does NOT deploy your code on Heroku.

What `heroku local` does is to run whatever processes you defined in your [Procfile](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile#procfile-naming-and-location). In your local dev environment, every [Process Type](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile#process-types-as-templates) in your Procfile will typically result in a single process when executed via `heroku local`. In addition, `heroku local` reads any env vars you define in a [local .env file](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-local#run-your-app-locally-using-the-heroku-local-command-line-tool), enabling you to test the behaviour of your [Heroku  config vars](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars).